# Installing node v8 in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, version, dockerfile, docker-machine

How do i install node v8 in Docker container. I would like to use node js version 8. What should my Dockerfile say in FROM line?

I currently have `FROM nodesource/node:8`, but doesn't seem to work. Any advice here?

Comment: Try `FROM node:latest` or `FROM node:8`.

Answer (score 2):

NodeSource was [last updated to version `6.3.0` a year ago](https://hub.docker.com/r/nodesource/node/tags/).

Use

```
FROM node:8
```

You can view available image tags for node on [the docker hub repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/).

Answer (score 0):

use 
`FROM node:8-alpine` which gives a low size node image
https://hub.docker.com/_/node/